# Why aren't I able to access the message text in my message queue using msgrcv()?

Tags: c, linux, message-queue, system-calls

I have build a program that allows me to create and delete message queues as well as send and receive messages.

Everything seems to be working correctly with the exception of receiving messages. When I receive the struct, I can access the type (which I've been using to denote the "recipient") and print it, however the string stored in the struct's msg field will not print. printf() seems to successfully access the mbuf.type field but not the mbuf.msg after using msgrcv(). I have tried debugging to figure out where the problem is, but I have been unsuccessful so far.

The message appears to be sent to the queue, as when I use "ipcs -q" to view my kernel's message queues, it will correctly display the number of messages I have sent. I am also able to access and print the msg field within that instance of the program in which I send the message. It is not until after the program exits and I restart it using the "-r" flag that I am unable to print the msg field.

I have included the code below, including the header file containing the definition of my message struct.

Please note: I understand that my validation is clunky and I plan on simplifying it once I get the program working properly. I apologize if it is confusing.

HEADER FILE:

```
#ifndef MESSAGE_BUFFER
#define MESSAGE_BUFFER

#define MSG_MAX 4056

typedef struct messageBuffer
{
    long recipient; //recipient of message
    long senderID; //id number of the sender    
    char msg[MSG_MAX]; //content of the message
}messageBuffer;

#endif
```

MAIN:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "message.h"


//function to print usage information upon error
void printUsage(){
    printf("Error: Invalid arguments\n"); 
    printf("Usage:\n");
    printf("(Create Queue) <-c/C> <key>\n");
    printf("(Send a message) <-s/S> <key> <recipient_id> <message>\n"); 
    printf("(Receive a message) <-r/R> <key> <recipient_id>\n");        printf("(Delete queue) <-d/D> <key>\n");
}


//main
int main(int argc, char **argv){

//declare necessary variables
char flag;
int msqid;
messageBuffer mbuf;
size_t buf_length;
int msgflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;
key_t key;
unsigned long recipient;



//validate arguments
if((argc < 3 || argc > 5) || argv[1][0] != '-' || strlen(argv[1]) != 2){    
    printf("%d\n", argc);   
    printUsage();
    return -1;  
}

flag = argv[1][1];


switch(flag){

        //Create a message queue
    case 'c':
    case 'C':
        if((key = atoi(argv[2])) < 1){
            printf("Error assigning key");
            return -1;
        }
        if((msqid = msgget(key, msgflg)) < 1){
            printf("Error creating queue:");
            return -1;
        }
        printf("%s%i\n", "Key: ", key);
        printf("%s%i\n", "msqid: ", msqid);
        break;

        //Send a message
    case 's':
    case 'S':
        if((key = atoi(argv[2])) < 1){
            perror("Error assigning key:");
            return -1;
        }
        if((msqid = msgget(key, 0400)) < 1){
            perror("Error accessing queue:");
        }
        mbuf.recipient = atoi(argv[3]);
        strncpy(mbuf.msg, argv[4], MSG_MAX);
        buf_length = strlen(mbuf.msg) + 1;
        if(msgsnd(msqid, &mbuf, buf_length, 0) < 0){
            perror("Error sending message:");
            return -1;
        }   
        printf("Message sent (%lu): %s\n", mbuf.recipient, mbuf.msg);

        break;

        //Receive a message
    case 'r':
    case 'R':
        if((key = atoi(argv[2])) < 1){
            perror("Error assigning key:");
            return -1;
        }
        if((msqid = msgget(key, 0400)) < 1){
            perror("Error accessing queue:");
        }
        recipient = atoi(argv[3]);
        if( msgrcv(msqid, &mbuf, MSG_MAX, recipient, 0)< 0){
            perror("Error receiving message:");
            return -1;
        }
        printf("Message received (%lu):\n", mbuf.recipient);
        printf("%s\n", mbuf.msg);
        break;

        //Delete a message queue
    case 'd':
    case 'D':
        if((key = atoi(argv[2])) < 1){
            perror("Error assigning key");
            return -1;
        }
        if((msqid = msgget(key, 0400)) < 1){
            perror("Error accessing queue:");
        }


        printf("%d\n", msqid);
        if((msgctl(msqid, IPC_RMID, NULL)) < 0){
            perror("Delete message queue failed:");
        }
        break;  

        //invalid flag
    default:
        printUsage();
        return -1;      
}






return 0;
}
```

I would appreciate any input. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with specifying the size of the struct that was being passed. I have changed the code "buf_length = strlen(mbuf.msg) + 1;" to buf_length = (sizeof(mbuf.msg) + 1);